# Is it possible to define in one swagger.json file two endpoints that are working on the different hosts?

Tags: swagger

Here is an example how to describe endpoint `http://api.example.com/get/{sensorId}/` in `swagger.json`:

```json
{
  "swagger": "2.0"
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "host": "api.example.com",
  "paths": {
    "/get/{sensorId}/": {
      "get": {
         ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Usually I create swagger definitions for the endpoints that are situated on the same host. But now I want to describe several API endpoints that are situated on the different hosts. The obvious solution is to create separate `swagger.json` for every host, but I
would prefer to documents that endpoint in the same file. That endpoints are a part of the same API, thats why I would like to document them near each other (there is one hostname that is used to read data and the other hostname to post data).

But it looks like this is not possible. The field `host` is specified on the top level of JSON file. But maybe I'm missing something and there is some way to specify different hostname for different endpoint in the same `swagger.json`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with OpenAPI 3.0. You can specify `servers` field. https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/

```json
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0"
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "host": "api.example.com",
  "paths": {
    "/get/{sensorId}/": {
      "get": {
        "servers": [
          {
            "url": "https://other-api.example.com"
          }
        ],
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```